Select Rows Based On Foreign Key In One-To-Many Relationships In SQL
I have a posts table and users table. And posts table has a column for author_id (foreign key). This is clearly an example of a One-To-Many relationship. I want to get all posts written by a specific user, say the one with ID 9.
That's my (naive) approach:
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE author_id = 9;

The problem with my naive approach is that I think it's very expensive for larger tables with more rows. Imagine if I have to go though all the comments posted on a social media platform just to get all the comments for that single post. That doesn't make sense!
It would be much better if I can access all posts related to a specific user by just accessing the users table. Is there any way to do that? If not, that's just a thought, so, are there any better approaches to my problem?
I use Sqlite3, but the question is not specific to a certain RDBMS, though I still want common and mainstream SQL, any answers with PL/SQL or some other more radical SQL won't be helpful for me.

This question is similar to: many-to-many relationship in database design. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users? [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Apply an index on author_id to make it faster and less expensive. Other approaches will be more expensive and complicated.
